# clang: cannot cast to private base while there is a public virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I'm trying to compile the following code (somewhat minimal example), file `test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> 

class Shared : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Shared>{
public:
    int prea;
};

class Widget : public virtual Shared{
    int a;
public:
    ~Widget(){
        a = 7;
    }
};

class Container : virtual public Widget{
};

class List : private Container, virtual public Widget{
public:
    int c;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    auto c = std::make_shared<List>();
    c->c = 3;

    std::cout << c->c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Using `clang++` as follows:

```
clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1106:50: error:
      cannot cast 'List' to its private base class 'const enable_shared_from_this<Shared>'
          __enable_shared_from_this_helper(_M_refcount, _M_ptr, _M_ptr);
                                                        ^
```

See full output [here](http://pastebin.com/m7d4NFPN).

Then, if I compile the same code using g++, there is no error and it produces the executable. And I would say that this is the result I expect. No idea why clang++ doesn't like the code.

So, the question is who is right? `clang++` or `g++`?

*Edit*: can be reproduced even on smaller example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> 

struct Shared : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Shared>{
};

struct Container : virtual public Shared{
};

struct List : private Container, virtual public Shared {
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    auto c = std::make_shared<List>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, can you compile this with clang's standard library? As you can see, clang by default on *nix systems uses gcc's standard library. Maybe this is a bug specifically when clang compiles gcc's standard library code. Edit: I quickly tested it on coliru, it seems like the standard library does not make a difference, but OP maybe you should verify this.

Comment: Much smaller repro case (consider updating question): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56d44d6bf2ce459b

Comment: It works if you just use `class List : virtual public Widget, private Container`.

Comment: @skypjack nice finding! Well, then it is clearly a bug in the compiler, since the order matters.

Comment: found this bug https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=28591 which looks somewhat similar

Comment: Submitted a bug: https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=32180

Answer (score 0):

I see support for this in both clang-3.4.1 and later, and gcc-4.7.1 and later. [Example in Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/MZmVoP)